# Find where Chunks, Snippets, and TV's are being used (MODX)

Tags: php, web, content-management-system, modx

Trying out a new system (MODX) where file structure and naming convention is different from what i'm used to.

Is there a search feature I'm missing, or a way to figure out where certain chunks/snippets/TV's are being used throughout the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not yet, not that I am aware of.

You could write a little script to scan for chunk/snippet names in the database fields and read the TV tables to see where they are being used, but that can be unreliable as you can also call/use snippets and chunks from within snippets, plugins and even external files [you can load modx externally as well]

Of course resources, chunks, snippets etc can also be saved as file based - so you would also need to scan the file system. :(